# Bind Keyboard shortcut to paste in xterm

Tags: linux, xterm, exceed

I use Exceed during work. I wanted to bind the keys `alt v` to paste in the terminal. I can't seem to get it working. I usually connect to other servers using xterm. Does anyone have a way of doing this? I know about `Shift Insert` but the insert is far on my keyboard and also a bit loose. I also know about using the middle mouse button, but I feel its a bit of hassle.
I looked around and only found help for gnome terminal and Ubuntu terminal.
I am using Exceed on windows 7.
I found this university link which says you can use

```
right alt v
```

but that just opens up a new file in home.
http://www.udel.edu/topics/connect/sw/exceed/docs-6.2/UD-Exceed-how-to-use.html

I also looked through the exceed documentation but didn't find anything.
Thanks